# Migrating from Joomla 3 to Joomla 4 router alias problem

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-4.x, router

In my old router.php file at `function COMPOENTParseRoute($segments)`, I get "404 Page not found". The error is caused by line 153 of `/libraries/src/Router/Router.php`.

If I create the new Joomla4 folder structure like `components/com_banners/src/Service/Router.php` and debug, that Router.php is not touched.

In the documentation, I read something like:

> Pay special notice to the lines starting `$container->registerServiceProvider` as this is where your code gets registered in a container for use later.

Do I need to do something special?

Comment: Have you already created a `services/provider.php` file? If so, what are its contents?

Comment: No i did not create that file, I think that was the problem, thanks.